# How to unpack tuples within a list to use in map

Tags: python

I'm just going to simplify my problem a bit. I have a function like this:

```
def func(a,b):
   return a+b
```

I also have a list of tuples which I would like to map to this function.

```
num = [(0,4),(6,3),(2,2),(9,1)]
```

I want to be able to map the tuples within the list like (a,b) to the function I provided.

In javascript you could acheive this by changing the function definition like so:

```
def func((a,b)):
    return a+b

num = [(0,4),(6,3),(2,2),(9,1)]
map(func,num)
```

This obviously doesn't work in Python. I know that I could also just pass the tuple into the function and then return `tuple[0]+tuple[1]`, but I didn't know if there was a cleaner option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`map` won't perform unpacking without writing a wrapper function to do that actual unpacking for you. That's [why `itertools.starmap` exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

def func(a,b):
    return a+b

num = [(0,4),(6,3),(2,2),(9,1)]
for result in starmap(func, num):
    print(result)
```

The name "starmap" is referring to the implicit star-unpacking operation it performs, making it equivalent to `map` with the iterable assumed to contain pre-packed iterables of arguments that must be `*`-unpacked, changing from `map` being the equivalent of `(func(x) for x in iterable)` to `starmap` being the equivalent of `(func(*x) for x in iterable)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need tuples, you can unpack it like this:

```py
def func(*args):
    return sum(*args)
```

If you want both integers and tuples passed to this function, you could try something like this:

```py
def func(a, b=None):
    if type(a) == tuple:
        return a[0] + a[1] # or sum(a) if you want all values added
    return a+b
```

If you want to do this with other iterables, change `type(a) == tuple` to `isinstance(e, Iterable)`, but remember to do `from collections.abc import Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

there are several options for that

```
>>> num = [(0,4),(6,3),(2,2),(9,1)]
>>> def fun(a,b):
...     return a+b
...
```

you have the starmap variant of map from the standard itertools module

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(fun,num))
[4, 9, 4, 10]
>>>
```

you can use list comprension and to manually unpack the arguments

```
>>> [fun(item[0],item[1]) for item in num]
[4, 9, 4, 10]
```

you can use the unpack operator

```
>>> [fun(*item) for item in num]
[4, 9, 4, 10]
```

unpack the arguments directly from the for-loop in your comprehension

```
>>> [fun(a,b) for a, b in num]
[4, 9, 4, 10]
```

use a lambda function to pass the arguments in your map

```
>>> list(map(lambda x:fun(*x),num))
[4, 9, 4, 10]
>>> list(map(lambda x:fun(x[0],x[1]),num))
[4, 9, 4, 10]
```

and more esoterically unpack the inverse of zip into your map

```
>>> list(map(fun,*zip(*num)))
[4, 9, 4, 10]
```

the inverse of zip is simple `zip(*my_zip_list)`

```
>>> list(zip(*num))
[(0, 6, 2, 9), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to approach this at the function definition level, you can change the signature to accept a single parameter (which must then alway be a tuple).  Then unpack the tuple internally in the function itself

```
def func(ab):
    a,b = ab
    return a+b
```

If you need the function to work both ways, you can make the internal unpacking and signature a bit smarter:

```
def func(ab,*b):
    a,b = (ab,*b) if b else ab
    return a+b
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick:

```
num = [(0,4),(6,3),(2,2),(9,1)] 

res =[sum(tuple) for tuple in num]
```

[4, 9, 4, 10]

Comment: We simply just don't want to unpack it, we also need to add it.

Comment: thanks for letting me know, just fixed it.

Comment: This still does not address the question OP is asking. Sure, it does the same thing OP's code would do, but it _doesn't answer the question!_